# Local and remote git repos are different, but indicate "Already up to date"

Tags: git, github

Help! My git repos are in a pickle!

Pushing and pulling local and remote branches says `Already up-to-date.` But examining the files reveals differences between them.

This is complicated by the fact that I have two local branches, master and staging, each tracking remote versions of the same.

I've spent a few hours trying to work out a systematic way to sort this out. But I'm worried I'm going to make it worse and lose edits in the process.

Is there a recommended approach in these cases?

**EDIT**

```
->git remote show origin                 
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:mygits/myrepo.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:mygits/myrepo.git
  HEAD branch (remote HEAD is ambiguous, may be one of the following):
    master
    staging
  Remote branches:
    master  tracked
    staging tracked
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master  pushes to master  (up to date)
    staging pushes to staging (up to date)
```

Comment: Clone your remote branch in to another place first in case you mess it up down the line.

Comment: Are you sure that `git status` is clean?  Assuming that's the case, it's important for people to be able to help that you explain which your current branch is, and exactly what form of the `git pull` and `git push` commands you're using, in particular if you're specifying additional arguments.

Comment: Please show the commands you're using, so we can see how the branches are being used.

Comment: thanks! i've added details about the branches to my original question. I started with master, then created a staging branch. These are tracking remotes on github with `git branch --set-upstream staging origin/staging` and `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master`. These are also being pushed to heroku for deployment. I'm fairly confident that the local branches are most up to date. However I'd like to resolve this in such a way that I can view differences between local and remote if possible.

Comment: hi @mark. no my git status is not clean. the differences between remote and local are listed `# deleted:    path/to/deleted/file.html` But I can not push these changes to the remote. `git push origin master` `git push origin staging` reveal  `Already up-to-date.` Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AndyHarvey: you can't push those changes because you can only push committed changes.  `git status` isn't showing you the differences between your a remote version and a local version, they're differences between the last commit, the index (or "staging area") and your working tree (i.e. the actual files on disk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'git remote origin show' indicates that master and staging are identical.  So it may be no surprise that both are 'Already up-to-date' but it depends on what you have locally.   Explore a bit with:

```
git fetch origin
git diff --name-status master..origin/master         # ditto for 'staging'
git diff --name-status master..staging                  # local differences
```

With these three 'diffs' (two shown, one more for 'origin/staging') you'll have an understanding about what git thinks are the differences between the commits on your four branches.

You still have the question of differences between what is in your working directory but 'git status' will show you those and they are not relevant to your pushing and pulling problem.  (If anything local differences will prevent pulling which you don't indicate as the problem.)

Comment: thanks GoZoner. git is listing differences, and indicating that files have been deleted. But push is also stating everything is up to date. I also can not pull for the same reason. I have just done `git reset --hard <<most recent commit ref>>`. This has added back several files that have been deleted previously. I don't appear to have lost any additions. I've not tried to `git add .` and `git commit -m "msg"` but is saying `Changes not staged for commit:` and I am still unable to push as `already up to date`. This is puzzling!

Comment: ok i just tried commit -a and that seems to have got things moving again. I can now push. I'm still not sure if I've lost any edits. I'm still finding my way around git. Does a hard reset followed by a commit -a sound like a reasonable solution to this. Are there any side effects I should be looking for?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are lacking basic information about a single user workflow.  Search for 'git tutorial'.  Generally you probably want to avoid 'git reset' as you risk losing stuff.  But, really, if you are trying variations of 'git add' and 'git commit' then you need some tutorial information.